# Is there a Hotelling's T2 function for multivariate data using python?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, python, threshold

I am looking at a multivariate time series data, which looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to create a threshold, so that when a huge peak comes up (like the one in the picture), it will output an alert.

The resource that I've found suggested Hotelling's T2 to calculate the threshold.
https://blog.pivotal.io/data-science-pivotal/products/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-for-virtual-machine-capacity-planning

So, does anyone know if there's any packages or functions for Hotelling's T2 in python. I've checked pandas, numpy and statsmodels, but can't find any. Not sure if it's under a different name or something.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

spm1d package contains many statistics, especially for multivariate time series data like yours.

for example Hotelling’s T2 test see:
http://www.spm1d.org/doc/Stats1D/multivariate.html

Comment: We are looking for long answers. This is rather a comment. As soon as you have enough reputation you can comment everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to install:

- Python package `rpy2`
- R package `Hotelling`
- Anaconda if you haven't already

Then you can use a Jupyter Notebook to [run both Python and R](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/01/pipelining-r-python.html) in the same Notebook.  Once you've started the Jupyter Notebook, run:

`%load_ext rpy2.ipython`
`%R require(Hotelling)`

And you should be able to run the analysis you need.